# Reactjs save and update the same user info with the same ID

Tags: reactjs, forms, authentication, user-input

This is my [User Settings page](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-stallman-7vnx0?file=/src/services/InfoService.js).

I created a button that is used to save and edit the info.

I would like that once the info is saved the first time, the app would register the user ID in order to update the info instead of creating new lines in the database.

In the sandbox you find the code I wrote, but it doesn't work. In the sandbox it didn't work because obviously there is no back-end, but that's not the error I'm referring to. The problem I think is in the "services" folder and in this piece of code:

```
if (info.id === null) {
      InfoDataService.create(data)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('create', response.data);
          setInfo({
            id: response.data.id,
            email: response.data.email,
            firstname: response.data.firstname,
            lastname: response.data.lastname
          });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.error(e);
        });
    } else {
      InfoDataService.update(info.id, data)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          setInfo({
            id: response.data.id,
            email: response.data.email,
            firstname: response.data.firstname,
            lastname: response.data.lastname
          });
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.error(e);
        });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-glade-3z67y?file=/src/UserInfo.js

I've mocked your API in infoService.js so it would at least do something, but you should be able to remove those lines and it will work locally for you.

Hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: it works just like I wanted. The only problem is that my app doesn't update and creates a new ID every time.
In your codesandbox you have set id: 123, I have removed that part of the code.
I would like the ID to be unique for each user and on the basis of that then perform the update.

Comment: @FrancescoEsposto What should happen is your InfoService.create should return an id, which will get set into info. Perhaps your backend code isn't returning the id correctly?

What does it show in the brackets after User information? It should be (unsaved) at first, then change to an id - if that's not happening, your post /api/users endpoint might not be returning the id as expected.

In InfoService.create, perhaps console.log the data returned, and you might see the id is missing, or perhaps is named differently, or the wrong case (ie ID not id)

Comment: The first time I click "save", the object is created successfully.

I click "edit" , modify an info , click "save" and it is updated correctly.

At the third time he gives me the error: "Request failed with status code 500" XHR PUT localhost:8080/api/users/undefined.

Response. JSON: Error updating User with id=undefined"

When i update for the 3th time I have this error already:


But I don't think it has anything to do with that.

Comment: So something is going wrong between the second and the third.

Looking at what happens, your second save will call `InfoDataService.update` (UserInfo.js:71) which will call the `update` endpoint (user.controller.js:50)

The problem is that your `InfoDataService.update` call is then expecting a response, which it tries to update with setInfo on line 74.

But your update endpoint is a PUT request, and so doesn't (and shouldn't) actually return anything. I think if you zero in on the console.log on line 73, you'll find it's empty.

So the fix would be to remove the setInfo on line 74.